# Why doesn't squaring both sides produce extraneous roots here?

Tags: radicals, square-numbers

$$\sqrt{\frac{\left(x-2\right)^{2}+\left(y-3\right)^{2}}{\left(x+1\right)^{2}+\left(y-4\right)^{2}}}=\frac{2}{3}...(i)$$

$$5x^{2}+5y^{2}-44x-22y+49=0...(ii)$$

(i) is the original equation, and (ii) is the simplified version of (i), which I have found by squaring both sides of (i). Even though (ii) is the squared version of (i), the graphs of the two equations are [identical](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/velhkyan5e). Why is this the case? Why doesn't (ii) have extraneous values?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/568917/768162) might help you in answering the question.

Comment: If you know that $\,a,b \ge 0\,$ then $\,\sqrt{a}=b \iff a=b^2\,$, which is what you have here.

Comment: The same reason why the graphs of $\sqrt{x+y}=4$ & $x+y=16$ are identical.

Comment: "Looking from above" (in Cartesian space $(x,y,z)$), the two expressions represent different geometric species, but in the plane $z=0$, they have the same section which is a circumference.

Comment: Any spurious solution produced from squaring would represent $\sqrt{\frac{\left(x-2\right)^{2}+\left(y-3\right)^{2}}{\left(x+1\right)^{2}+\left(y-4\right)^{2}}}=-\frac{2}{3}$ and that is clearly impossible if the square-root function only produces non-negative numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, $a(x)=b(x)$ is equivalent to $a(x)-b(x)=0$, while $a^2(x)=b^2(x)$ is equivalent to

$$0=a^2(x)-b^2(x)=(a(x)-b(x)(a(x)+b(x)).$$

The last equation shows where extraneous solution come from when "squaring": they are solutions of $a(x)+b(x) = 0$.

It just so happens that in your case, where $a(x)=\sqrt{\ldots}$ and $b(x)=\frac23$, which are both non-negative (and the second actually positive), so their sum can never be zero!

In addition, in practical work with such equations, extraneous solutions also come from non-rigorously defined (or simply not computed) domains for the variable to be calculated.

For example, the equation

$$\sqrt{x+1} = \sqrt{x^2+2x-1}$$

has a single solution in $\mathbb R$, namely $x=2$. The squared equation

$$x+1 = x^2+2x-1$$

however has 2 real solutions: $x_1=2, x_2=-1$. The extraneous solution $x_2=-1$ comes from the fact that the original equation is meaningless for that $x$ value (when considering real numbers only). The original equation only makes sense (when working with real numbers) when $x \in [\sqrt{2}-1,\infty).$

Confined to that domain, the squared equation has no extraneous solutions.

But in a real world scenario, you often do not bother making a complete analysis of when the original equation is well-defined (which may be a harder problem than solving it!), but you apply squaring and other "non-equivalent" techniques and then have to remember that the solutions you find at the end are just "candidate solutions" for the original equation.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple.  The equation states that the square root of some quantity equals $2/3$.  If you square both sides, it just means that the quantity must equal $4/9$.  Nothing has changed, because the only way the LHS can equal $2/3$ is if we take the positive root of the quantity inside the root.

Another way to put it is to consider a simple example:
$$\sqrt{z} = 3.$$
In this case, what is the solution set for $z$?  It cannot be anything else besides $9$.  There is no introduction of an extraneous solution.

Then, why is it that extraneous solution are introduced for, say,
$$z = 9 \implies z^2 = 81?$$  In this case, squaring both sides introduces the solution $z = -9$ because the act of squaring lets us choose a negative value, which when squared, becomes positive.  But this is not permitted in the square root situation above, since $\sqrt{-9} \ne 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider two equations:

$$\sqrt{x+y}=4...(i)$$

$$\sqrt{x+y}+x=4...(ii)$$

Now, in equation (i),

$$\sqrt{x+y}=4$$

$$\iff x+y=16...(iii)$$

Again, in equation (ii),

$$\sqrt{x+y}+x=4$$

$$\implies x+y+2x\sqrt{x+y}+x^{2}=16...(iv)$$

(i) & (iii) are equivalent equations (graphs are [identical](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y1ueysunik)), but (ii) & (iv) aren't (graphs aren't [identical](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qanfnmag5p)). For this reason, (iii) doesn't have extraneous roots but (iv) does.

Comment: @Ingix 's answer is better